# DataView getFloat32 returns incorrect but approximate numbers

Tags: java, javascript, floating-point, arrays

I'm using websockets on a java server (jetty) to send values (float numbers) as bytes and DataView.getFloat32 (created from an ArrayBuffer) to extract them in my javascript code.

My problems is that numbers appear to be incorrect (but almost equal to the actual values), for example:

if I send 2.43, in javascript it outputs 2.430000066757202 or in other cases, something like 2.439999340243.

In java i use ByteBuffer:

```
byte[] numberBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(number).array();
```

and the output of the getFloat method is correct :

```
number = ByteBuffer.wrap(numberBytes).getFloat(); //returns 2.43
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens ?

**EDIT:**
Regarding the floating point precision, my issue is that if i use double, that would mean a double traffic for my application - I need to send packages of 50-100 numbers, 10 - 15 times per second, at least, and for a large number of clients.

Comment: Almost *everyone* knows why it happens. Read up on what a "floating point number" means.

Comment: I know it's about floating point representation and 32 bit precision can cause such behavior, but i thought that javascript's getFloat32() function would take care of the problem (approximate correctly) :D

Comment: What i don't understand is why does the java code work ? 
number = ByteBuffer.wrap(numberBytes).getFloat();
System.out.println("Number: " + number); //this prints correctly, not 2.430000066757202

Comment: It's just the way the number is *printed*. See the rules for that [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString(float)).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Because i only need to represent the numbers on client side, in javascript, i found out the correct way to display float numbers as string, when needed a given precision (5 decimals in my case), is to use number.toPrecision(...) function.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from Javascript floating point numbers that are 64 bits. See [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), which is not on the Javascript/Java subject but explains why floating point numbers are not *exact*.
In your case, if you do the simple `Java` test :

```
float f = 2.43f;
double d = (double)f;
System.out.println("as float: "+f+", as double: "+ d);
```

You will get :

```
as float: 2.43, as double: 2.430000066757202
```

If precision matters for your application, try to stay compatible with `double` values on both sides, or use `integer` values with a *scale* or *precision* additional information, e.g, rather than `flat number = 2.43f`, use `int number = 243; int scale = 100;`

Comment: The issue is that if i use double, that would mean a double traffic, for my application. I need to send packages of 50-100 numbers, 10-15 times per second, so I'm in a bit of a struggle here... So are there any other alternatives

Comment: An alternative would be to send unsigned int (32 bit) and scale by 10000 (because i need 5 decimals precision). That would mean that the actual maximum number i could send is 42949.67296 right ?

Comment: Depending on the range of your numbers, integers could be a good bet. The additional `scale` may be shared between numbers and the overhead reduced. What's the range ?

Comment: Well, 10000 should be maximum, but i'm not sure at this point (could be 100000 and this would not work). But isn't there an approximation method/algorithm that could suit this case ? I tried toFixed(5) but for 269.02 outputs 269.01999 (from 269.0199890136719, which is obvious)

Comment: I came across [this](https://github.com/spencertipping/flotsam), with the [blog entry](http://blog.factual.com/the-flotsam-project-insanely-fast-floating-point-number-serialization-for-java-and-javascript) that explains the rational. Looks really good and advertised to work for 32bit floats and 64bits. I haven't tested though.

Comment: Given the fact that on client side (javascript) i only need to represent numbers as strings (but with precision of 5 decimals) and all additional calculations are on server side, i will use number.toPrecision(5) function (instead of toFixed(5)(, which is correctly represented when displayed as a string.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the representation of float numbers, not getFloat32() function. In my case, because i needed to work with a precision of 5, I was using number.toFixed(5), and I should have used .toPrecision(5), when displaying the numbers as strings.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to DataView.getFloat32() being lazy.

What you expect, is that the binary data in your ArrayBuffer should be read as a float, which has enough mantissa bits for 6 ~ 9 digits of precision, so it gets rounded when viewed as a decimal number, and then that value is assigned to a variable that is a double. Because these floats and doubles have different bits in the mantissa for different precision, you can expect completely different mantissa when representing the exact same decimal number. (And we are always talking about decimal numbers, nobody uses floats to represent binary numbers. See also [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985))

For example, 2.43 in float is `0x401B851F` and 2.43 in double is `0x400370A3D70A3D71`. You can just eyeball the hex representation to see it has totally different mantissas.

However, the implementation of getFloat32() as seen in the [source](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/js/src/builtin/DataViewObject.cpp) is exactly as described in T.Gournelle's answer. DataView.getFloat32() calls setDouble() which takes a double as a parameter, so this causes an implicit C++ floating point conversion from float to double. That C++ conversion makes the double value equivalent to the float binary value, not its decimal value.

So when you get 2.430000066757202 in double, that's `0x400370A3E0000000`. You see that `0000000` in the end of the double's mantissa? That's the getFloat32() being lazy by simply doing a C float to double cast rather than actually getting you the float value.

All this means, is that you have to take the extra step of rounding to 6 or 7 digits yourself after performing a getFloat32().

(Note: I'm making this a separate answer since T.Gounelle's answer gives the background of floating point precision, but does not actually answer the OP's question regarding getFloat32 causing precision errors.)